# Sampling rows in 2D numpy arrays with replacement

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random

[`numpy.random.choice`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html#numpy-random-choice) is a handy tool for sampling random elements from a *1D array*:

```
In [94]: numpy.random.choice(numpy.arange(5), 10)
Out[94]: array([3, 1, 4, 3, 4, 3, 2, 4, 1, 1])
```

But the docs specify that `a` param *must* be one dimensional. But if I want to get a random selection of rows from a 2D array (for example, random samples for a one hot encoder), then `numpy.random.choice` cannot be used anymore.

So if my input is:

```
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.]])
```

How can I get n rows in random fashion from this array, like this? (n = 10)

```
array([[ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per [this](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5344) issue, the feature was considered in 2014, but no substantial additions have been made to the API since then. There is, however, a better solution that cleverly makes use of `numpy.random.choice` and numpy's fancy indexing:

Starting with

```
In [102]: x = numpy.eye(3); x
Out[102]: 
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.]])
```

You may use `numpy.random.choice` to generate a list of random indices, like this:

```
In [103]: i = numpy.random.choice(3, 10); i
Out[103]: array([2, 2, 0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1])
```

Then use `i` to index `x`:

```
In [104]: x[i]
Out[104]: 
array([[ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.]])
```

With a workaround this efficient, I don't believe a change to the API is necessary.

Do note that, for generating rows with a certain probability distribution, the procedure is the same. Specify a probability distribution on the indices itself.

Comment: this is essentially a for-loop method ... which is kinda ugly, especially for numpy. Isn-t there a better way?

Comment: @robertotomás what makes you think this is essentially a for loop? Everything here is vectorised. I don't think they've come up with something better yet.

Comment: I just realized that that wasn-t _for i in i_, it was the whole thing at once :) thank you

Answer (score 2):

Just to add another way of selecting rows from a 2-D array using the `numpy.random.Generator.choice` approach. Half-way through the page on the link below  https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html it indicates that "*sampling random rows from a 2-D array is . . . possible with Generator.choice through its axis keyword.*"

This approach works with pandas dataframe too. The only thing is that it changes dataframe to arrays after the sampling. Which you can easily convert back to dataframe.

Piggy-backing off what `cs95` did, you could do the following:

```
x = np.eye(3); x

# numpy.random.Generator.choice
rng = np.random.default_rng()

y = rng.choice(a=x, size=10, replace=True, axis=0)
y

array([[0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1.],
       [1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.]])
```